# codeigniter 3 $query = $this->db->query($queri_str); return 0 result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

Good morning,
I have a problem with mysql and coeigniter 3.
if I request data with

```
$ query = $ this-> db-> query ($ queri_str);
```

it does not give me results.
if I enter the query on phpmyadmin it shows me two results.

```
$ queri_str = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE` id_mytable2` = "'. $ id_name. '"';
```

The database tables were created with mysql workbench and automatically the reference to the main table with a 1: n ratio was added

Comment: print your last query using codeigniter and check it.

Comment: my last query is SELECT `data` FROM `ci_sessions` WHERE `id` = '58e5j0m5bqrs7hk8suokko28hj7ni0v6'

Answer (score 1):

**Try this query**

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', '58e5j0m5bqrs7hk8suokko28hj7ni0v6');
    $result = $this->db->get('ci_sessions')->result_array();
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: result print 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 58e5j0m5bqrs7hk8suokko28hj7ni0v6 [ip_address] => ::1 [timestamp] => 1544088965 [data] => __ci_last_regenerate|i:1544088681;username|s:7:"johndoe";email|s:21:"johndoe@some-site.com";email1|s:21:"johndoe@some-site.com";email2|s:21:"johndoe@some-site.com";logged_in|b:1; ) )

Comment: so you got the result.

Comment: but the problem is that I'm calling the query from a model does not hit anything with ci_sessions how do I clean up the status of the queries and set up a new one

Comment: so can you explain me what you want to do?

Comment: previous I used only $ this-> db-> query ($ queri_str);
instead using:
$ This-> db-> select
$ This-> db-> where
$ This-> db-> get
returns the values ​​of the new quey.

Comment: yes you forgot that, for object you can use result() and for array you can use result_array(). for more info you can refere CI doc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, you want to do a normal select,I don't know the query your wrote but

```
public fucntion get_data($id){

     $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('your_table');
    $this->db->where('id','=' ,'$id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
     $data = $query->result_array(); 
     return $data;
   }
```

Comment: doing this function the result is empty while if I do it in phpmyadmin it gives me two results

Answer (score 0):

the problem is back.
I'll explain.

```
function myfunction($id_myname) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id_myname', $id_myname);
    //$query = $this->db->get('my_table');
    $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
    //print_r($query);
    //var_dump($query);
    if ( !$query ){
        $error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'
    }
    return $query->result();
}
```

when I call this function an empty value comes back to me.
While if I enter the value of the query in phpmyadmin I find two values

Comment: use the query I sent you.it's much simpler to understand,from your query codeigniter doesn't know whether to return a row or an array.try the code i gave you before you add anything else

Comment: function myfunction($id_myname) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id_myname', $id_myname);   
    $query = $this->db->get('my_table');   
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $data = $query->row(); 
          return true;

       }
       return false;
}

Comment: public fucntion get_data($id){

     $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('your_table');
    $this->db->where('id','=' ,'$id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
     $data = $query->result_array(); 
     return $data;
   } the result is empty,but if write select in phpmyadmin return two result.

Comment: are you sure ,you have the db credentials correct is your config file?

Comment: let me see where you are calling this function in your controller

Comment: $data["array_view"] = $this->MO_mymodel->myfunction($this->input->post("id")); if I print the select created and put it on phpmyadmin it gives me the right result of two records

Comment: I also use database credentials for other queries that work

Comment: in autoload file : $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: replace $this->input->post("id") with  $_POST['id'], if it will work